# How do I create a nupkg that just contains files?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I'm trying to create a NuGet package that just deploys some scripts used by the build system and general developer utilities.

Here's the `.nuspec` file contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <metadata>
    <id>Some.Scripts</id>
    <version>1.0.0.0</version>
    <title>Some Script Library</title>
    <authors>Some Developers</authors>
    <owners>Some Developers</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Contains scripts for general use in coding or build and deploy automation.</description>
    <releaseNotes>Initial release.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2015</copyright>
    <tags>PowerShell scripts automation TeamCity build tools</tags>    
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src=".scripts\**\*" target=".scripts\" />
  </files>  
</package>
```

The folder structure on disk is:

```
\GitRepos\Some-Scripts\
\GitRepos\Some-Scripts\Some.Scripts.nuspec
\GitRepos\Some-Scripts\.git
\GitRepos\Some-Scripts\.scripts\
\GitRepos\Some-Scripts\.scripts\someScript.ps1
```

NuGet.exe 3.3.0.212 produces this error message:

> Cannot create a package that has no dependencies nor content

Is what I'm doing even possible?

**Update**

I originally posted an answer:

> Okay, I think I have found the problem. It doesn't like the leading period in the source folder .scripts though its cool with it in the target folder.

Though actually that solved only half the problem. Though it makes a package and the files are in it (viewed in WinZip) the installation fails with:

> Could not install package 'Some.Scripts 1.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

**Update 2**

Found this bug report on the NuGet GitHub but its been closed after some work in an area that, to me, seems unrelated.

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1021

Answer (score 1):

Add a dummy file to /lib, e.g. `<file src="foo.txt" target="lib/" />`

see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38221710/52479