# Microsoft.Preview.WindowsAzure.ActiveDirectory.Authentication could not be installed targets NETCore, Version = v4.5

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget

The base of the problem:

> We wish to access [Dynamics CRM Web API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt770386.aspx), one of the steps in doing so is getting the [App registered](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt622431.aspx). To do that we need [redirectURI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531010.aspx#bkmk_redirect), that URI in turn requires [`WebAuthenticationBroker`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40084724/2404470). We're doing all this Nuget struggle for `WebAuthenticationBroker` thing

When installing Nuget package [`Microsoft.Preview.WindowsAzure.ActiveDirectory.Authentication`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Preview.WindowsAzure.ActiveDirectory.Authentication/)

Inside **Visual Studio Premium 2013 Update 5**, we're getting the below error:

[image: Microsoft.Preview.WindowsAzure.ActiveDirectory.Authentication could not be installed. The package targets the following frameworks: .NETCore, Version = v4.5]

Inside **Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Update 3**, we're getting the below error:

> Could not install package '`Microsoft.Preview.WindowsAzure.ActiveDirectory.Authentication 0.6.1`'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '`.NETFramework,Version=v4.5`', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Btw, The `.NET Core` is installed:

[image: dotnet --version]

But doesn't shows up in (either version of) Visual Studio:

[image: .NET frameworks]

Tried to solve the issue with the following guides:

- [The project is created from scratch.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38500047/2404470)
- [Mapped with versions v3 to v4.6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34463557/2404470)
- [Created a folder `Microsoft.Preview.WindowsAzure.ActiveDirectory.Authentication.0.6.1` inside packages folder of the project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38221710/2404470)
- Tried with a [sample project](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/web-authentication-d0485122) which uses `WebAuthenticationBroker`, found that it requires **Windows 8.1** to work in Visual Studio

[image: Project requires Windows 8.1]

Comment: I think the exception is kinda self explanatory. The Nuget Package itself is not compatible with .Net Framework 4.5. By the time that package was released, there was no 4.5 anyways :) Try going for a lower version of target framework if you must work with that package maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking inside the Microsoft.Preview.WindowsAzure.ActiveDirectory.Authentication 0.6.1 NuGet package contains one lib directory with assemblies and that is **netcore45**.

The netcore45 target framework is Windows 8 so you can only add the NuGet package into a project that is compatible, such as a Windows 8 project, or a Universal Windows application.

Comment: We wish to access [Dynamics CRM Web API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt770386.aspx), one of the steps in doing so is getting the [App registered](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt622431.aspx). To do that we need [redirectURI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531010.aspx#bkmk_redirect), that URI in turn requires [`WebAuthenticationBroker`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40084724/2404470). We're doing all this for this bloody `WebAuthenticationBroker` thing

Comment: I test it in my side, I got the same result using web apps, my understanding is that this package was used for the Windows store app. So the real issue is that it just supports the specific project type.

Comment: @student, what about this issue? Whether it could help you resolve and understanding this issue? I think Matt provided the correct answer, of course, it seems that it also supports VS2015 UWP apps:)

Comment: @MattWard How does one can see inside a **Nuget** package? Also, the issue seems to be of OS, not that of the project type

Comment: @JackZhai the issue seems to be of OS, not that of the project type

Comment: @student, what is your OS? I just test it in my windows 10 Environment with VS2013 and VS2015, but as far as I know, the windows 8.1 or windows 10 Environments would support the store apps. Do you resolve this issue now? NuGet Package Explorer tool could help you view the Nuget package's contents/files.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 and it seems to be the issue of the OS only

Comment: @student - A NuGet package (.nupkg) is basically a .zip file with a different extension. So a simple way to look inside is to rename the file extension to be .zip and then extract the files using Windows built-in zip file support.