# Can't create a nuget content only package

Tags: nuget

I'm merely trying to create a nuget content-only package published to an in-house repository that I can reference from a .Net framework 4.6.2 project.  When I attempt to install the package using Visual Studio 2017, I get the error:

*"Could not install package 'MyPackage'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author."*

I'm packing/pushing the package using nuget.exe, version 4.6.2.

A coworker created a content-only package that installs fine.  During his package installation, I see in output:

*Adding package 'HisPackage', which only has tools group, to project 'SameProject'*

However, even if I pattern my nuspec file exactly after his, I get the same results.  The relevant portion of his nuspec looks like:

```
<package>  
  <metadata>  
  ..  
  </metadata>  
  <files>  
    <file src=".\init.ps1" target="tools\init.ps1" />  
    <file src=".\some.exe" target="lib\some.exe" />  
    ..  
  </files>  
</package>`
```

Things I've tried:
- `<files><file src="whatever.txt" target="ParentDir\any" />`
- `<files><file src=".\whatever.txt" target="tools\whatever.txt" />` just like coworker's
- `<files><file src=".\whatever.txt" target="content\whatever.txt" />` exactly as specified in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#including-content-files)
- `<files><files include="content/SomeDir/**/*" buildAction="None" />`(based on [this](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3668) even though it's old)
- `<contentFiles><files include="SomeDir/**/*" buildAction="None" flatten="true" />`
- `<contentFiles><files include="./SomeDir/*.*" buildAction="None" />`
- `<contentFiles><file src="SomeDir\**" target="tools" />` thinking "tools" like the output message above
- `<contentFiles><files include="whatever.txt" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true" />`
- Using neither files nor contentFiles.  Still packages up what's in the same directory as the .nuspec.
- Same as above but putting my content in a parent content dir.
- All the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34463262/nugets-install-in-visual-studio-2015)
- [Converted project to PackageReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference).  This caused the package to install without error, but no content was ever delivered.  This despite many permutations of contentFiles, folder structure, etc.

Comment: What is your nuget version? In Visual Studio you are using package.config or PackageReference? Did you try target specific framework like `target="lib\462\some.exe"`

Comment: nuget version 4.6.2 (as I mentioned), package.config, I don't want to target a framework; it's just content.  I want it to just work as the coworker's package.

Comment: Can you include the full content of your coworker's nuspec file, and your nuspec file?  This link https://blog.nuget.org/20160126/nuget-contentFiles-demystified.html seems to suggest that you need the contentFiles node in your metadata node, but you trimmed that.

Comment: I thought I'd start with the coworker's files and nuspec, get that working and go from there.  The package files don't match the nuspec he gave me, so we don't have his original nuspec.  Nonetheless, his package proves it can be done.  Somehow.